# Как объединить 2 while с одинаковым условием в один?

Tags: java, while

Нужна помощь в упрощении кода. Как можно объединить два цикла в один? Буду Вам очень благодарен. Вот его часть (в которой нужно объединить циклы):

```
public class uuu {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String s = "bbbAAbbbCCbbb";
        String t = ""; // AAbbbCCbbb
        int i = 0;
        while (i < s.length()) {
            final char ch = s.charAt(i);
            if (ch != 'b') {
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        while (i < s.length()) {
            final char ch = s.charAt(i);
            t += ch;
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если я все правильно понял, то это может быть цикл for

Answer (score 0):

```
bool flag_not_b = false;
while (i < s.length()) {
    final char ch = s.charAt(i);
    if (!flag_not_b)
        flag_not_b = ch != 'b';
    if (flag_not_b)
        t += ch;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну если уж совсем упрощать, то все циклы можно заменить одной регуляркой.

```
public class uuu {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String s = "bbbAAbbbCCbbb";
        // убирает все символы b в начале строки
        String t = s.replaceAll("^b*", "");
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```